# Derive the equations needed to compute the shortest distance from a point a set.

Tags: linear-algebra

Derive the equations needed to compute the shortest distance from a point, $P$, to the set $O = \left\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x} = b\right\}$ where $\mathbf{a}$ is a 3-vector and $b$ is a scalar.

Also, compute the shortest distance from a point, $P$, to the set if the set, $O = \left\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}\right\}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $3\times3$ matrix and $\mathbf{b}$ is a 3-vector.

I'm looking for guidance on how to work these problems out?

Answer (score 0):

So, in fact, for the first part, $O$ is a plane $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{a}=b$.

Letting $\overrightarrow{OP}=\mathbf{p}=\left(\begin{matrix}p\\q\\r\end{matrix}\right)$, what can you say about the length of project of $\overrightarrow{OP}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$?

> We have the distance from the origin to $P$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$ as $\mathbf{p}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{a}}$.

We know that the distance from the origin to the plane $O$ is $\frac{b}{\|\mathbf{a}\|}$.

> So the distance is simply $$D=\left|\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot\mathbf{a}-b}{\|\mathbf{a}\|}\right|\text{.}$$

Very similar logic applies to hyperplane as well.

Comment: Can you tell me how you figured out in the first part that O is a plane?

Comment: @Pete honestly it's quite a bit by observation kind...